# Issue with viewing the react-app build on desktop

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm just getting started with a React App and attempting to run the `npm run build` command for the default app without any modifications.

Here's the content of `my-app/build/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.8381e2a9.js"></script>
    <link href="/static/css/main.f855e6bc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to open `my-app/build/index.html` on my desktop with any browser; it displays a blank page. In the browser's console, I see the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND main.f855e6bc.css:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /C:/favicon.ico:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:1 Access to internal resource at 'file:///C:/manifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
```

Assuming that the issue is in the file paths in `my-app/build/index.html`, I changed them to absolute paths. The page now opens, but the React logo is not showing. There's still an error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND logo.6ce24c58023cc2f8fd88fe9d219db6c6.svg:1 
Access to internal resource at 'file:///C:/manifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted. index.html:1
```

I expect the build to run properly without errors, and without manually changing any lines in `my-app/build/index.html`. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You can't open the file directly, you need an HTTP server to serve it. Why aren't you simply using the dev server locally? `npm start` - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#npm-start-or-yarn-start

Comment: See also https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment